# Get values from the handle function

Tags: matlab, handle

I am using the following code to fit a model to my data.

```
load fisheriris
x = meas(51:end,1:2);
y = (1:100)'>50;
cp = cvpartition(y,'k',10);
f = @(xtr,ytr,xte,yte)(predict fitglm(xtr,ytr,'linear','Distribution','binomial','Link','logit'),xte)
cfMat = crossval(f,x,y,'partition',cp);
cfMat = reshape(sum(cfMat),2,2)
```

How can I get the predicted values given by the handle function? I mean the  column vector containing the fitted values.

I am working with MATLAB R2014a

Comment: `Error: Unexpected MATLAB expression.` (Matlab 2014b)

Comment: Yeah that `predict fitglm()` breaks my parser as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the parenthesis in the correct place:

```
f = @(xtr,ytr,xte,yte) predict(fitglm(xtr,ytr,'linear','Distribution','binomial','Link','logit'),xte);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: @Liza Thanks for choosing my reply as the answer. :-)

Comment: In fact I had the parenthesis in the wrong place, but what I really want is the column vector containing the fitted values obtained in f. Why I can not see these values in the results?

Comment: @Liza Unfortunately you can't do that, because `crossval` does not expect the fitted values, but the labels of the classification. If you really want to do that, is better to create a .m file that will have your function writing the fitted values somewhere in a global variable.